# ARC is trying to retain invalid memory

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

All,
The EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception is being thrown when objc_retain is being called by the framework.  Any help or tips tracking down the problem would be appreciated.  Let me know if I should provide more code.

Problem Area:

```
- (SCUuidNode*)addUUIDNode:(NSString*)uuid
{
    const char *uuidCStr = [uuid cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    SCUuidNode *uuidNode = [[SCUuidNode alloc] initWithNode:create_uuid_node(uuidCStr)];
    composite_node_append_child((Node*)[self node], [uuidNode node]);

    return uuidNode; # Exception is being thrown right around here.
}
```

...

```
Composite *paymentNode = [SCCompositeNode createPriceNode:^(SCCompositeNode *cnode) {
    SCUuidNode *uuidNode = [cnode addUUIDNode:buyerDeviceId];
    SCIntNode *buyerIdNode = [cnode addIntNode:[buyerUserId integerValue]];
}];
```

Comment: product -> edit scheme -> diagnostics, in memory management section check box for  Enable Zombie Objects

Comment: Am not sure...but why to use `char *` cant use `nsstring` ?

Comment: yes that i understood, if you use nsstring, then ARC will be in work right?

Comment: Thanks guys, that helped and looks like it will help me track it down better when I have more time.

Comment: maybe the problem is with cStringUsingEncoding: - The returned C string is guaranteed to be valid only until either the receiver is freed, or until the current autorelease pool is emptied, whichever occurs first. You should copy the C string or use getCString:maxLength:encoding: if it needs to store the C string beyond this time.

Comment: Yes, ARC will clean up a NSString, but create_uuid_node(uuidCStr) uses a cStr.  The cStr created by NSString from  [uuid cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] still is controlled by the NSString, which is copied by the c lib.

Comment: There is more going on here.   How is `initWithNode:...` implemented?

Comment: @bbum, yup was initWithNode:, once I checked it out after enabling zombies the '[SCUuidNode class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8ad9b30' message pretty much lead me right there.  I completely left out the whole init function other than _node = node; lol.  Thanks everyone problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

As rob and Space Dust kindly pointed out, adding zombies helped track down the memory bug to an initializer.